# How to get only the date part from Different Time Zone C#

Tags: c#

Trying to get the Date of a different country (time zone) and then display it. I'm getting the time and date. Just need the date

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.Date, info);

    MessageBox.Show(dateTime.Date.ToString());
```

Need 05/05/2015 but not the time

Comment: Do you need to support Globalization, is the application being used in many countries or just one location.

Comment: To format a `DateTime` to string and get different formats, check the documentation for `ToString`, it accepts a parameter dictating the format, or use `.ToShortDateString()`.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(dateTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

Comment: @ZiedRebhi that assumes UK datetime format, the application might be used by different cultures that have different date formats.

Comment: `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.Date, info)` will return the same value for each day (local timezone). This is probably not intended and you should drop the `.Date` part.

Comment: In addition to dropping the `.Date` part, like @Dirk suggests, I'd also switch to `DateTime.UtcNow`. It's silly to convert from utc to local time, back to utc and then to the target time zone, when you could directly convert from utc.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use directly

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToShortDateString());
```

or else you can customize it

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `date` only by using `ToShortDateString()`

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.Date, info);

MessageBox.Show(dateTime.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

Or you can directly use

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: This works very well if the Current Culture is correctly set.

Comment: You should replace `DateTime.Now.Date` with `DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a format in any case, if you want to specify the culture for a specific country you can do it, or use one of the method of the class DateTime(ToShortDateString(), ToLongDateString(), etc)

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

or `var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` explore CultureInfo for more information

Then use the ToString method to obtain your date in the specific format, see that format does not include hour or minutes.

```
dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", provider)
```